# Dirichlet Boundary Condition finite difference method using sparse-matrix $Ax = b$ system

Tags: pde, finite-difference, parallel-computing, numerical-modelling

I am trying to solve the boundary value problem for heat equation:

$$
u_{xx}  + u_{yy} = f(x,y)
$$

where the solution $u(x,y)  \in [0,1] \times [0,1]$ and the Dirichlet boundary condition $u(x,y) = u_0$.

So I discretized the problem with $N$ interior points with step size $h = 1/(N+1)$

$$
w_{i,j-1} + w_{i+1, j} +  w_{i-1,j} - 4 w_{i,j} + w_{i, j+1} = h^{2} f(x_{i}, y_{j})
$$

where $i,j \in \{1,2,...,N\}$ and the boundary conditions are:

$$
w_{0,j} = w_{N+1, j} = u_{0} \quad\quad\quad w_{i,0} = w_{i,N+1} = u_{0}
$$

where $i,j$ is from $1$ to $N$

I reduce this problem into sparse-matrix system. I know how to make the sparse matrix $A$ for this problem by using Python. The only issue is the RHS which is matrix $b$. For the case of $u_0 = 0$, I  trivially evaluate the grid points at function $f(x,y)$. For the case $u_0 \neq 0$, I do not know to retrieve matrix $b$. I tried to write down with the case $N = 3$ to see the general pattern as below (I put in column-order):

[image]

I hope anyone could help me understand how to retrieve that matrix $b$ in general case for Dirichlet boundary condition??. The code I wrote for this problem is in Python, but I want to understand the generality first.

Comment: It may be useful to think about it in 1D first. The matrix equation at a boundary grid point $(i,j)$ should express the relation $w_{i,j}=u_0$, so the corresponding entry in matrix $A$ should be 1, and in vector $b$ is should be $u_0$.

Comment: But then it would be totally different from this problem. Isn't it? The discretization in 1D problem is taking 3 stencils point. Meanwhile in this, I think it is 5 stencils (grid points)

Comment: I see what you are saying. If $A = I$ which is the identity matrix, then you are left with $\vec{w} = \vec{b}$ where $\vec{b}  = h^{2} \vec{f} - \vec{U_{0}}$. So unless all $f_{i,j} = 0$ then you have the relation $w_{i,j} = - U_{i,j}$

Comment: On the boundary $f$ should not be present, only the boundary condition relation $w_{i,j}=u_0$

Answer (score 1):

A general way would be to include the boundary nodes in the definition of $A$ (which will give you a matrix with more columns than rows) and derive $b$ as the contribution of the Dirichlet nodes. This way, other linear terms like convection are readily included.

Assume that the matrix $A$ looks like

$$
A = [A_I | A_\Gamma ]
$$

where $A_I$ is the (square) operator on the inner (as you have it in your question) and where $A_\Gamma$ are the columns that belong to the boundary nodes. It is not a problem to resort the columns like this, but in `python` I would rather work with the indices and slices.

Then the $b$ is extracted as

$$
b = - A [0 \dotsm 0|u_0 \dotsm u_0]^T = -A_\Gamma[u_0 \dotsm u_0]^T.
$$

In fact, your solution reads $w=[w_1 \dotsm w_{N^2} | u_0 \dotsm u_0]$ and will solve
$$
Aw=f \quad \text{ or } \quad A_Iw_I + A_\Gamma w_\Gamma = f \quad \text{ or }\quad  A_Iw_I = -A_\Gamma w_\Gamma + f \quad \text{or}\quad  A_Iw_I = b + f ,
$$
where $w_\Gamma$ is your solution at the boundary nodes.
We have once explained this approach for Finite Elements discretizations in a preprint[^1](https://doi.org/10.14293/S2199-1006.1.SOR-MATH.AV2JW3.v1) but the principle is the same for Finite Differences.